# How to mix two raster in R (same extent)?

Tags: raster, r, merge, combine

I want to produce one PNG image for each country in the world. The pixel colors come from a [`raster`](https://www.iscgm.org/gmd/) that describes the vegetation, and the boundaries of the countries come from a [`shapefile`](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip).

I managed to do almost all of it using the `raster` and `rgdal` libraries in R:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('gm_lc_v3.tif')
library(rgdal)
p <- readOGR('ne_10m_admin_0_countries','ne_10m_admin_0_countries')
i <- 66 # Dominican Republic, a small country for fast example
country <- crop(r,p[i,]) # produces the rectangular crop below
plot(country)
```

[image: no_mask]

```
m1 <- mask(country,p[i,]) # crops on the country boundary
plot(m1)
```

[image: mask1]

```
m2 <- mask(country,p[i,],inverse=T) # crops outside the boundary
```

[image: mask2a]

```
m2[m2 < 20] <- NA # turns all land into NA
```

[image: mask2b]

What I need now is to combine the two rasters (m1 and m2) into a single raster, with all data from the country, and only land/water data from outside the country. Like this (made in Gimp):

[image: maskFinal]

I have tried all the following so far, but without success:

```
m3 <- cover(m1,m2)
m3 <- cover(m1,m2,identity=T)
m3 <- merge(m1,m2)
m3 <- overlay(m1,m2,fun=function(x,y){return(x+y)})
m3 <- mask(m1,m2)
m3 <- stack(m2,m1)
```

They return all black, or different colors from the original. What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing all your NA's to 0 (assuming no 0s in the grid) then just add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with merge, only the colortable was missing:

```
m3 <- merge(m1,m2)
m3@legend@colortable <- m1@legend@colortable
plot(m3)
```

or

```
m3 <- merge(m1,m2)
m3@legend <- m1@legend
plot(m3)
```

[image: maskFinal]

Comment: I think there must be a faster way to do it, though.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `plot` (look at the help from package [raster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf)) with the argument `add = TRUE`

```
plot(m2, col='black')
plot(m1, col=rev(terrain.colors(255)), box=FALSE, axes=FALSE, add = TRUE)
```

Or Try this

```
plot(m1)
image(m2, add = TRUE, col = 'black')
```

Comment: It doesn't work, with or without the 'col' parameter.

Comment: Also tried using the 'alpha' parameter, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Rodrigo 
 
In which way 'it doesn't work?'

Comment: With 'col' (like you used it), I got a big square over the (correctly merged) map. Without the 'col' parameter, the second plot simply erases the first (what's strange, because the 'add=T' is still there, and all the NAs really should have become transparent).

Comment: @Rodrigo I updated the code. Better?

Comment: Not better. Also updated your question, so you can see what's going wrong.

Comment: Anyway, if that works, it'll be producing a plot, not a new raster, that was the original question (it will be ok now, but possibly not in a different case).

Comment: @Rodrigo: the way you use mask is wrong. Not the plotting

Comment: What is wrong in the way I used mask?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44112/discussion-between-nebi-and-rodrigo).